# Fast Creation of Label Matrix for Use With ComponentMeasurements?

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, image-processing

I am taking a lot of measurements from regions of interest in microscopy images and am finding that generating binary masks to use with ComponentMeasurements is rather slow (at least it's slow the way I am doing it).  Are there any faster ways to generate a label matrix than going through Binarize and Graphics or can Binarize and Graphics functions be made faster with Compile and/or Parallel?   Below is how I make a binarized polygon mask the same size as the cropped microscopy image I am working with:

```
computeImagePropertiesFromMask[ptsIn_, 
   imageIn_] := (


   binMaskFromPtsIn = 
    Binarize@
     Graphics[{White, Polygon[ptsIn]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{1, 600}, {1, 600}}, 
      ImageSize -> {600, 600}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Background -> Black];

   compMeasureStatsFromMaskOnImage = 
    ComponentMeasurements[{MorphologicalComponents@binMaskFromPtsIn, 
      imageIn}, {"MeanIntensity", "StandardDeviationIntensity", 
      "TotalIntensity", "Area"}];


   (* stats returned for the mask all have label 1 in the matrix \
generated by MorphologicalComponents *)

   compMeasureStatsFromMaskOnImage$Label1Stats = 
    1 /. compMeasureStatsFromMaskOnImage


   )
```

Typical AbsoluteTiming I get is around 0.40 seconds and generating the binarized mask (binMaskFromPtsIn) seems to be the slow step.